# is it possible to get directions like compass using accelerometer without using magnetometer in android?

Tags: android, accelerometer, magnetometer

I am trying to get directions in my Application but i had facing problem with magnetometer. i need get directions from accelerometer with out using magnetometer (like compasss does) . please any guide me . how to do that using acelerometer ? is it possible?
Thanks in Advance.